# Remove all child elements associated with a specific node and replace with a single child element

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm new to XSLT, but I do a lot of XML modifications for work so I'm trying to learn.  I have input XML in the following format (there's XML above and below it):

```
<Parent Value="x">
<!---->Unlimited number of child elements could exist with any value from 0-1
    <Child Value="0.1"/>
    <Child Value="1"/>
    <Child Value="0.30"/>
    ...
</Parent>
```

I need the Parent/Child node **output XML** in the following format:

```
<Parent Value="x">
    <Child Value="0.3"/>
</Parent>
```

Where there is only one child element and its value is constant at 0.3.

My **current XSLT** kind of works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-datatypes">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Parent">
    <Parent>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*"/>
        <Child Value="0.3"/>
    </Parent>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Child[@Value!=0.3]"/>
```

I was trying to create the desired child element in all files (in case it didn't exist)

```
<Child Value="0.3"/>
```

and then only output the child element if its value=0.3.  However, this sometimes results in duplicates of the child node, and I feel like I might not be approaching this the right way.  Also, the xmlns:xs headers appear after the Parent element rather than at the top of the output document.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

**Example of current output:**

```
<Parent Value="x" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-datatypes">
    <Child Value="0.30" />
    <Child Value="0.3" />
</Parent>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only two things that need to be amended:

**1** Use single quotes here:

```
<xsl:template match="Child[@Value!='0.3']"/>
```

If you don't, the value is interpreted as a *number*, otherwise as a string. Why does this matter? Because if the right side of the expression is a number, the attribute value is converted to a number, too - and `0.3` and `0.30` end up being the same. Which eventually leads to multiple `Child` elements being output.

**2** Make the deliberate insertion of a `Child` element conditional, using an `xsl:if`. Obvously, depending on whether this particular element already exists in the input. Then, you do not get two `Child` elements in the output.

Note: Any child node of `Parent` that is not an attribute or element node (i.e. `processing-instruction()` and `comment()`) is simply ignored in your stylesheet. This is because you apply templates to `@*|*` only, not to `@*|node()`.

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-datatypes">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Parent">
    <Parent>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*"/>
        <xsl:if test="not(Child[@Value = '0.3'])">
            <Child Value="0.3"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </Parent>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Child[@Value!='0.3']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Input**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Parent Value="x">
    <Child Value="0.30"/>
    <Child Value="1"/>
    <Child Value="0.4"/>
    <Child Value="0.3">The right one</Child>
</Parent>
```

**XML Output**

```
<Parent xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
        xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-datatypes"
        Value="x">
   <Child Value="0.3">The right one</Child>
</Parent>
```

Currently, there are unused namespaces in your output XML. You may want to prevent them from appearing in the output by adding `exclude-result-prefixes="#all"` to `xsl:stylesheet`. If you do, then the output is simplified to

```
<Parent Value="x">
   <Child Value="0.3">The right one</Child>
</Parent>
```

Comment: I can't tell you how helpful this is!  It completely makes sense.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with an identity-based transformation, but you probably need to create the single Child in a template for the *parent*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Child"/>

<xsl:template match="Parent">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <Child Value="0.3"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```